# List<String> with entities to encode to UTF-8

Tags: java, utf-8

I have list which get regex value and add to List

```
private static List<String> listaOfQuestion(Scanner sc, List<File> listaQuestion) {
    List<String> question = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (File input1 : listaQuestion) {
        try {
            sc = new Scanner(input1);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
            Scanner s = new Scanner(sc.nextLine());
            while (s.hasNext()) {
                String words = s.nextLine();
                try {
                    question.add(getTagValuesQ(words).toString());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return question;
}
```

I want to parse all value like

**List**
Biela`&#x144;`ska
Wyzi`&#x144;`ski
Wci`&#x15B;`lik

To

**List**
Bielańska
Wyzińska
Wciślik

To UTF-8, i'm searching throught the forum, and i didn't see solution or i just dont get it. 
I appreciate every form of help, but because i'm new the best will be standard example or something like this which i will be able to understand.

I solved my problem, i needed use

```
<...>
Scanner s = new Scanner(sc.nextLine());
    while(s.hasNext()){
        String words = s.nextLine();
String decoded = org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4(words);
<...>
```

Comment: Where do you want to do the encoding?  I can't see any examples of where it would be used in your code.

Comment: There is another constructor of Scanner : `public Scanner(File source,String charsetName)` , where you can specify a charset .

Comment: @Berger That would be decoding, but it's the best guess at what the OP meant. +1

Comment: sorry my colige from work visit me, i edit my question really sorry.

Comment: Berger i used Scanner like that

for(File input1 : listaQuestion){
     try {
        sc = new Scanner(input1,"UTF-8");
     } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
     }
but it's doesn't work. I'm sure that your solution is fine but i think that i try to do this in wrong way.

Comment: I found this, can you try:

http://www.idryman.org/blog/2013/10/03/convert-uf8-literals-in-java/

Comment: I checked this read all try implement but he have string "\xe6\x84\x8f\xe6\xb3\x95\xe5\x8d\x8a\xe5\xaf\xbc" which he put in code. I need to get for example .log file with names, addresses, ect. like this 
<name>Biela&#x144;ska</name>
<address>street Biela&#x144;ska</address>
use regex to get names and addresses to list of value and try to convert values in this list if contains hex code. :)
Ofc. thank you friend but i looking for something else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried using Apache Common Lang and solved it:

```
    String s = "Biela&#x144;ska Wyzi&#x144;ski Wci&#x15B;lik";
    String decoded = org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4(s);
    System.out.println(decoded);
```

Output:

```
Bielańska Wyziński Wciślik
```

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/download_lang.cgi